# What happened to the Subsonic CMS/Starter Site

Tags: subsonic, content-management-system

I think SubSonic used to have CMS (or Start Site) web application available, but for the life of me I can't find it.

Rob [mentioned it on his blog](http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/subsonic-new-project-site-online/) a year ago when he moved the site to Graffiti CMS, and the [Google Code project site](http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/) has a reference to it to:

> A solid foundation from which to extend. Our starter site comes pre-wired with ASP.NET membership built in, AJAX, full 3-column elastic XHTML theme, and user administration pages from which you can administer your site's membership. That's at least a week's worth of work - already done!

But I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know where it is, or what happened to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the Starter Site project has been rebranded the SubSonic CMS and moved [here](http://code.google.com/p/subsoniccms/). The old starter site is available via an old svn revision at the main SubSonic Google Code repository [here](http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/source/browse/?r=146#svn/trunk/StarterSite).